# Deriving from std::stringstream

Tags: c++, double, stringstream, c++98

In my project I need to combine doubles and strings in one string. There are multiple options to choose for the above, but taking into account precision issues (I need to convert doubles with some specific precision), I've decided to use `std::stringstream`. There are a lot of places where I need this concatenation, so, setting precision for each conversion is not convenient (currently used precision may be changed in future, or I can forget setting precision somewhere).

I could define some function that creates a `stringstream` object, sets its precision and returns the created object, but I'm using c++98 and there is no support for copy constructor.

So, I've decided to derive from `stringstream`class like below, and in my code use `Stringstream` objects only:

```
class StringStream : public std::stringstream {
    public:
        StringStream(std::streamsize prec = 12) : std::stringstream() {
            precision(prec);
        }
};
```

And this does the work. But am I deriving correctly or is this a good way to implement what I need?
Or maybe there is a way to set precision for `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: Can't you create a new type (e.g. class or structure) and then just overload the input and output operators to handle your type? That way it will be more generic, and you can use any kind of streams with your type.

Comment: I can, but what I need is just the same stringstream with precision sat. Seems the simplest way to go is deriving. Or I'm missing something, and doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can read this: http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/parallel/pgi/doc/pgC++_lib/stdlibug/cre_2288.htm

Comment: I'm just a little bit worried that it's too opaque, hard to understand *why* your class has to be used, and easily forgotten to use your special class. Otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: You could define your own manipulator `default_precision` (like `setprecision`, but with a fixed value) . Then use `stream << default_precision` for each new stream.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Joachim Pileborg, I can still use `std::stringstream` with doubles somewhere :(

Comment: Choosing different name could help with transparency. Like `precisionstringstream`.